# Give permission to administrator to view the plugin page

Tags: wordpress

I am developing my own plugin.

Under my plugin's directory I have a file called migrate.php. I would like to be able to navigate to this page, without having it be in the left menu.

When I go to

```
admin.php?page=myplugin/migrate.php
// ERROR: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

How can I grant permission to the administrator to view this page ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the page view is failing because the slug you are using isn't defined as a slug (ie by being added as a menu or submenu).

You could work around this by calling the PHP file directly, but then you'd need to include the WordPress loader to load the WordPress environment.

Hope this gets you a little closer ...